# "to be made" vs"that are made"

Tags: infinitives

> I believe that the advantages of buying a property greatly outweigh the short-term savings to be made by renting.

In above sentence what is the role of `to be` in ("to be made")? Can I write "that are made" instead.

I guess "to be made" is the short for "that are intended to be made" if this is correct is this structure  a general structure and can be use in other similar situations?

Answer (score 1):

As @P.E.Dant suggests, *to be* is expressing futurity.

> I believe that the advantages of buying a property greatly outweigh the short-term savings to be made by renting.

In this context, *to be* is used as a [modal verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs) in the first person singular, and is replacing, "that would be", or, "that could be", or "that should be". Note that *would, should, and could* are also modal verbs.

Ex:

> I believe that the advantages of buying a property greatly outweigh the short-term savings *that could be* made by renting.

Check out [this link](http://linguapress.com/grammar/to-be.htm#modal) for more details & examples.

Lastly, its worth noting that *to be* is also conveying a degree of uncertainty, or opportunity. Its not necessarily guaranteed that savings *will* be made, just that they *can* be made.

Comment: I think you are misled by the heading at `linguapress.com`: in expressions like *He is to be ...* the 'modal' piece is not the infinitival complement *to be* but the form of *BE* which acts as the main verb--*is* in this example. *CGEL* Ch 3, §2.5.7, p. 113-4 calls this *BE* a 'quasi-modal': "in spite of its one modal property (and its modal meaning) this *be* doesn’t in fact qualify grammatically for inclusion in that class."

Comment: @StoneyB Heh! Leave it to H&P to state the thing with impenetrable squishiness. _To be_ here acts like a modal on _make_, conveys futurity and supposition like a modal, but it _isn't_ a modal? Verily, _quasi_ forgiveth a multitude of sins.

Comment: I read the Linguapress piece early in the game but found, as @StoneyB points out, that this _be_ is a different case. In those examples, some degree of obligation is conveyed, and the modality is in the _am, is,_ and _are_ forms (e.g.: _"...savings he is to make"_) and not in the infinitive. Here, _to be_ is also masquerading as part of a passive infinitive, which adds more confusion.

Comment: @P.E.Dant H&P follow the 'standard' use of the term *modal verb*, which is restricted to defective auxiliary verbs which must occupy the front position in verb constructions. It's an unfortunate term--there are lots of things (most of which aren't even verbs or verb constructions) which communicate modality--but H&P are pretty conservative about introducing new terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I think "to be made" is infinitive modifying "savings", which is equal to "that are to be made". Although you could probably use "that are made" instead, the meaning would be slightly changed because infinitive "to be made" implies things would be done in the future. Sometimes, I would consider this kind of "to be" is short for "that is/are to be". like, this is the decision (that is) to be made.

Comment: What kind of infinitive is _"to be made_"? How does an infinitive imply things that are done in the future?

Comment: isn't an infinitive common to express the future? eg. "We want our students to enjoy the course."

Comment: @P.E.Dant *To-* infinitivals may be deployed as adjectivals with future or deontic sense (deonitics are inherently futurive): 1) as a predicative complement with *BE*: *I am **to return** by Friday* ... 2) As a postposed modifier: *a plan **to be** supported*.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.'To be made' means-something that should or needed to be done or made.On the other hand,'that are made' means-Something that's already made.Examples:'To be made'- There are some decisions to be made.So,this sentence means that there are some decision needed or should be made.'That are made'- Dishes 'that are made' by my mom are more delicious than hers.So, here it means that the dishes are already made and you are just commenting on her dishes.